# using PL/SQL table of records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to store some value and then retrieve the same, as we do using the oracle actual table.

I have the following package head:

```
 create or replace PACKAGE test_record AS
-- 1. Type definition      
type status_change_t is record (
    action                      varchar2(30),
    production_order    varchar2(30),
    job_status              varchar2(30),
    operator                    varchar2(200),
    reg_date                    date
);
-- 2. type table of record  

type status_change_table_t is table of status_change_t index by binary_integer;
-- 3. procedure where it is passed as parameter

procedure StatusChange(p_transaction_id in varchar2, 
     p_status_change_table in status_change_table_t);

 END test_record;
```

here the package body:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY test_record as

-- Procedure
procedure StatusChange(p_transaction_id in varchar2,
         p_status_change_table in status_change_table_t)
is
    l_app varchar2(50) := 'xxgex_test_record.StatusChange';
    l_status_change_rec status_change_t;
    l_return_status varchar(9000);
    l_job_status varchar(100);
begin
    --InitContext;
    --xxgex_util.debuglog(l_app, 'called');
    for i in p_status_change_table.first .. p_status_change_table.last loop
        l_status_change_rec := p_status_change_table(i);
        dbms_output.put_line('record ' || i || ': action = ' || p_status_change_table(i).action || '. production_order = ' || p_status_change_table(i).production_order || ', status = ' || p_status_change_table(i).job_status);

        --select job status
        select l.meaning
        into l_job_status
        from wip_discrete_jobs disc,
        wip_entities ent,
        mfg_lookups l
        where ent.wip_entity_name =  l_status_change_rec.production_order
        and ent.wip_entity_id = disc.wip_entity_id
        and disc.status_type = l.lookup_code
        and l.lookup_type = 'WIP_JOB_STATUS';

        --the job must not be in closed status
        if upper(l_job_status) = 'CLOSED' then
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Job must not be in Closed status');
            dbms_output.put_line('Job must not be in Closed status, job name:' || l_status_change_rec.production_order);
        end if;

        if upper(l_status_change_rec.job_status) = 'RELEASED' then
            dbms_output.put_line('invalid job_status: ' ||  l_status_change_rec.job_status);
        else
            dbms_output.put_line('invalid job_status: ' ||  l_status_change_rec.job_status);
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'invalid job_status: ' ||  l_status_change_rec.job_status);
        end if;

    end loop;

end StatusChange;

end test_record;
```

Now I am confused: how can I call this function?

Here is my executing script but it throws an error:

```
declare
  l_status_rec test_record.status_change_table_t;
begin
select class_code
into l_status_rec
from wip_discrete_jobs
where wip_entity_id= 226003;

test_record.StatusChange(1, l_status_rec);

end;
```

here is the error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - declare
>       l_status_rec test_record.status_change_table_t; begin   select class_code   into l_status_rec   from wip_discrete_jobs   where
>   wip_entity_id= 226003;
>        test_record.StatusChange(1, l_status_rec);    end; Error report - ORA-06550: line 5, column 8: PLS-00597: expression 'L_STATUS_REC' in
>   the INTO list is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 6, column 3: PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00904: : invalid identifier ORA-06550: line 4, column 3: PL/SQL:
>   SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2: question is now completely different

You are trying now to select a single column into a variable of table type having more than one column. I don't know your data model, but you should try to select all the columns this type requires, e.g.:

```
DECLARE
  /* 
  I renamed the variable in your original script from *_rec to *_tab as it confuses me an leads to think a record is used instead of table.
  */
  l_status_tab test_record.status_change_table_t;
BEGIN
  SELECT action
        ,production_order
        ,job_status
        ,operator
        ,reg_date BULK COLLECT
    INTO l_status_tab
    FROM some_of_your_tables
   WHERE come_id = 123;

  test_record.statuschange(1, l_status_tab);
END;
```

Comment: See my edited answer: test_record vs xxgex_test_record

Comment: how can I assign values to record and then send to function?

Comment: See my 2nd edit, you can use bulk collect to select into TABLE type variable.

Answer (score 1):

> PLS-00597: expression 'L_STATUS_REC' in the INTO list is of wrong type

Your record has five columns in its definition:

```
type status_change_t is record (
    action                      varchar2(30),
    production_order    varchar2(30),
    job_status              varchar2(30),
    operator                    varchar2(200),
    reg_date                    date
);
```

but your SELECT statement has only one column in its projection:

```
select class_code
into l_status_rec
from wip_discrete_jobs
```

The projection of the SELECT must match the signature of the INTO variable.

Comment: There is also a `select into` without a `bulk collect` into a collection type-- that doesn't make sense.  If the query is supposed to return multiple rows, you'd need a `bulk collect into l_status_rec` (naming a variable _rec when it is not a record but a collection of records is a separate issue).  If it always returns exactly 1 row, then you'd want to do a `select into` the record type not the collection type and the collection doesn't make much sense.

Comment: with correct projection got the following error. end;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 13, column 8:
PLS-00597: expression 'L_STATUS_REC' in the INTO list is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 14, column 3:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 12, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action: